# Could you show me a synonym for "let alone"?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage

> The baby cannot even yet sit up, ***let alone*** walk.

Would you please show me a synonym for the bold part?

Cheers,
Nima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much less, not to mention, and never mind; all will work well here